# Database sharding, denormalization and synchronization

Tags: database-design, sharding, data-synchronization, denormalization

In sharding, it is advisable to follow a *share nothing, shard everything* approach. Essentially, this translates to: data that are to be used together are to be stored together (i.e. in a single shard). This also fits in nicely with the split your data at the application level philosophy.

But it is not always practical to completely denormalize the data. Consider for example an eCommerce site. All data corresponding to an user should ideally be kept together. However, some data, like product availability will need to be synchronized throughout. In some cases, like the aforementioned one, this sync needs to happen real time. As an example, suppose a user has added products to their wishlist. In principle, all data about the wishlist items should be kept together with the rest of the user's data. However, multiple users can wishlist the same item, and other users can also buy the item, thus affecting its availability. Thus the information needs to be shared and sync'd in some way. The complexity and performance hit that would come from multiple joins is also well known.

To make the issue even thornier, it is to be expected that in the above example, or in any case requiring proper ACID transactions, the sync has to be practically real time. It might be acceptable if the number of likes is updated with a delay but it would be bad business for an eCommerce site to show delayed product availability data!

What's the best approach in cases like this?

One preliminary line of thought was to use a push/notification mechanism for such fields as availability, transaction status, etc. But I am really keen to hear from the experts. Obviously, I've read about eBay's architecture on [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com)but it doesn't go into this level of implementation detail.